# Subversion server statistics

Tags: svn, subversive

We have a subversion server (v1.8) which host around 500+ repositories , we would need to know the consolidated repository statistics without checking out (working copy)

The details we are interested in are the last commit by a user with date and time on all the repository

PS : I tried svn list --recursive -v file:///usr/local/svn/repos/xxxx >>/tmp/dc.log but it prints the whole history and the file grows big . I also tried SVNStat but does not work without checking out the whole repo...

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

How about [`svnlook`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnlook.c.info.html)?  It will return the author, time, and log message of a revision in a repository, and if you don't specify the revision it will operate on `HEAD` (i.e., the most recent revision).

Example from the SVN book:

```
$ svnlook info -r 40 /var/svn/repos
sally
2003-02-22 17:44:49 -0600 (Sat, 22 Feb 2003)
16
Rearrange lunch.
```

In your case, for a single repository:

```
$ svnlook info file:///usr/local/svn/repos/xxxx
```

*Note, the third line returned is log message size, in bytes.*

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanks for the inputs , i have already tried this , The issue with this is it gives me the last commit or change on a particular repo. what i am interested in is , List of commit made by a author in all repository. Ideally we would need to know if the user is activity committing in any repo

Comment: There's no SVN command that will act on all repositories below a certain folder on disk; they all operate on a single repository at a time.  However, it's easy enough to write a script to iterate the repositories and call `svnlook` on each one.